# Hide field from email composer screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using MFMailComposeViewController to send an email from my application but i want to hide some of fields from email composer screen. like i dont want to display email address in "To" field same like below image.

[image]

how to hide this email address in email composer or let me know if you have any alternative for this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MFMailComposeViewController and privacy - hiding the To: field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241152/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-and-privacy-hiding-the-to-field)

Answer (score 1):

MFMailComposeViewController's UI is not customizable however you can certainly pre-fill the fields from your code..